# Kronecker-Capelli theorem

Tags: linear-algebra

When we should use K-C theorem?

and when we can use different methods like Gauss method?

For example we have 3x4 matrix with parameter a:

```
1 a 3  | a
a 2 3  | 1
-1 a 2 | a+1
```

should we use K-C here?

Comment: You should diagnolize the matrix after that use K-C theorem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course we could, but i find Cramer's Rule more useful in this case. Compute the determinant to determine when the system is definite or not.

Comment: Is there any example when we can't use other methods? (only K-C work)

Comment: For example when we have more unknows than equations.